# CNG AES -> C# AES

Tags: c#, c++, aes

I want to make a program in C# that can open [KeePass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/) 1.x kdb files. I downloaded sources and trying to port password database reading functionality. Database contents is encrypted.  Encryption key is obtained the following way:

1. User enters password;
2. SHA256 hash of password is calculated and split in two 128-bit halves;
3. Several rounds of AES is applied to each half of hash using key from database header;
4. Halves are concatenated back;
5. Result is salted with salt from database header;
6. SHA256 hash of step 4 result is calculated. That is the encryption key.

I'm stuck on step 3. KeePass uses [CNG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for AES. Simplified source (for half of hash, other half had the same applied to it):

```
BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAes = NULL;
BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = NULL;
BYTE pbKey32[32] = <encryption key>;
BYTE pbData16[16] = <half of hash from step 2>;

BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAes, BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);

DWORD dwKeyObjLen = 0;
ULONG uResult = 0;
BCryptGetProperty(hAes, BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH, (PUCHAR)&dwKeyObjLen, sizeof(DWORD), &uResult, 0);

BCryptSetProperty(hAes, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, (PUCHAR)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_ECB, static_cast<ULONG>((wcslen(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_ECB) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)), 0);

BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB_32 keyBlob;
ZeroMemory(&keyBlob, sizeof(BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB_32));
keyBlob.dwMagic = BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB_MAGIC;
keyBlob.dwVersion = BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB_VERSION1;
keyBlob.cbKeyData = 32;
memcpy(keyBlob.pbData, pbKey32, 32);
pKeyObj = new UCHAR[dwKeyObjLen];

BCryptImportKey(hAes, NULL, BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB, &hKey, pKeyObj.get(), dwKeyObjLen, (PUCHAR)&keyBlob, sizeof(BCRYPT_KEY_DATA_BLOB_32), 0);

for (int i = 0; i < rounds; ++i)
{
    BCryptEncrypt(hKey, pbData16, 16, NULL, NULL, 0, pbData16, 16, &uResult, 0);
}
```

So, as far as I understand, it uses AES algorithm with ECB chaining mode and it passes `NULL` and `0` as 5th and 6th argument of [BCryptEncrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function meaning it will not use initialization vector.

Now, how do I do the same in C#? I wrote following function to do one round of transformation (based on MSDN sample):

```
    public static byte[] KeyTransform(byte[] buffer, byte[] key)
    {
        Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = key.Length * 8;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        //aes.IV = new byte[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        ICryptoTransform ct = aes.CreateEncryptor();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, ct, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(cs))
                {
                    bw.Write(buffer);
                }

                cs.Flush();
            }

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Then I compare buffers after one round of AES applied in original and in my code. My code produces different results from original. How do I fix it?

By the way, no matter if I specify IV or not my code produces different result every time (so I believe IV is always generated and used). If I try to set `aes.IV` to `null` it throws exception saying that I can't set it to `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that initializing ICryptoTransform like this:

```
ICryptoTransform ct = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
```

does the trick.
The only thing that worries me is that resulting memory stream has 32 bytes instead of 16. But if I drop last 16 of them it produces what I need.